# Different sized images affect my layout in unexpected ways (Android, Galaxy Tab)

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am using XML to layout a screen for my activity.  My goal is to have a background image for my Android activity with the rest of the interface on top of it.  The hardware is a Galaxy Tab (600x1024 screen), and it's forced into portrait orientation.  I've a substantial amount of experience programming but am new to the Android environment.

In general, I don't want to design to specific orientations and hardware; I am trying to simplify the problem and eliminate potential variables.

What I am finding is that the success, or failure, of the layout depends on the image used.  I'd like to plumb the collective wisdom here to see why, so I can at least predict when it will behave strangely.

The XML consists of a FrameLayout (full screen).  The first item within it is an ImageView, with the image I want to be stretched or shrunk to become the background of the screen.  The second item is a LinearLayout containing text, buttons, etc. for the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/mainFrameLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wbkgdlogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bkgdlogo"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        />
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0px">
```

I've left out the remaining portions of the XML file, as they should be irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Case 1: Success, sort of.
When the bkgdlogo.png file is small - 190x190 pixels - it is stretched to cover the screen and the remaining linear layout is set up the way I want it.  Unfortunately, the image I intended to use is bigger than that.

Case 2: Failure.
When the bkgdlogo.png file is large - 600x1024 pixels - it covers the screen, but the remaining linear layout is broken.  The first few elements are all crunched to the top of the screen, and then the rest are absent (or possibly offscreen, I suppose).

If I find no other answers, I will get a lower resolution image of the background logo to work around the problem... but it bothers me, since I won't know when the problem will hit again.

Is it just a problem with using images the size of the screen, or am I laying this out wrong somehow?

I've also tried using the image as a background to the LinearLayout and removing the FrameLayout.  The effects were worse - when my activity called the next one in sequence, the layout of the subsequent activity would be messed up in a variety of difficult to describe ways.

My suspicion is that I have missed a parameter, or am using the image view in an unintended manner, but I can't figure out what I missed.

Comment: As a followup: Case 3 uses a background which is 599x1023.  It works correctly.  So it seems to be a problem with a background bigger than the screen... but I can't find someplace which says when this happens.  On a smaller screen, do you get it with a smaller image, or is this really a Galaxy Tab problem?

Comment: Can't say I've run into issues on the Tab with backgrounds, but I'd always `android:background` rather than an ImageView. Is the image in the `hdpi` drawable folder? Anyway if you remove the ImageView entirely does the Layout always function as expected. Also there is no way settings the background of a View should affect a subsequent activity unless you're using static fields for storing views. Also is the image a NinePatch?

Comment: It is not a nine patch.  I tried android:background with similar failures, although I did not write down the details.  I agree that there is no way setting the background of a view should affect a subsequent activity, but should and does seem at odds here.